# Modifying Java classes at runtime to make instance fields transient -- will it work?

Tags: java, session, weblogic

We have an annoying log message coming from Weblogic whenever we invalidate the HTTPSession when it has objects that are not serializable (which we don't care about but which is polluting our logs). Tweaking our log4j configuration to not log this message does not appear to be an option (the message is coming from a generic Weblogic class and we dont want to supress all messages from this class and other than writing our own adapter to look at messages about to be written to the log and suppressing the deserialization error messages I dont know how we would do it through log4j configuration).

In order to temporarily fix this to clean up our logs I want to intercept calls to add objects to the HTTP Session so that the class of the object being added (and any objects in its object graph) have their instance variable declarations changed to transient. Figured I would intercept calls by adding an HTTPSesssionEventListener and then modifying the Class's instances variables using the reflection libraries.

Does anyone know if this would work?

Comment: Do you need to see your logs online?

Comment: Seems a horrendous hack to suppress a valid warning.

Comment: its not a valid error for our purposes (weblogic chose to log it at the ERROR log level-- when you're not replicating sessions or dont care that your objects arent serializable the ERROR level is inappropriate. Would be nice if it were configurable or that they would alter the log level depending on whether you were doing things like replicating sessions (and then having your objects being serializable matters).

Comment: It **is** a valid error, your application should be designed to be distributable. Just fix the real problem.

Comment: IIRC, objects stored in the session are required by the spec to be serialisable.

Comment: evidently you guys have never worked on a commercial project before-- to the business owners, this is not a business error and like i said, this is a temporary fix. we do plan on cleaning up the code we inherited to make everything properly serialized. there are simply too many instances we would have to fix and its to risky to fix all of the problems right now. we simply want to implement a temporary fix so that we clean up the logs. please stay on topic people. looking for help with this specific instance and not a political war here.

Comment: Finding a workaround will take more time than fixing the real problem (implementing `Serializable`, wow, soooo risky). But have fun with that. I can't help, I'm writing a HelloWorld tutorial.

Comment: yes... making changes to hundreds of classes in a production system with several code branches is risky and time consuming. even if the change is small.

Answer (score 2):

> Does anyone have a better suggestion and/or know if this will/will not work like I would want it to?

Yes. **Build to spec!**

In compliance with the Java Servlet specification:

> The distributed servlet container must throw an `IllegalArgumentException`
>   for objects where the container cannot support the mechanism necessary for
>   migration of the session storing them.

So if you want to avoid this message (and write good portable and distributable code), just make the object you put in `HttpSession` implement the `Serializable` interface.

Seriously, I can't believe you are thinking to a solution to workaround the real problem instead of fixing it.

Comment: i didnt write this code, i inherited it. this is an interim fix and not intended in anway to be a real fix. plan is to incrementily fix the app as quick as we can but we need the logs cleaned up now so that we can better debug other production errors.

Comment: Besides, how hard can it be to add "Serializable" with a decent IDE?  How long could it take - maybe a day's effort?  The hack will take longer than the fix.  +1 from me.

Comment: +1 - interim hack fixes are a bad idea.  Just fix it properly.

Answer (score 1):

One option if would be

```
tail -f yourlog | grep -v "annoying line here" > cleanLogFile
```

Which is much less intrusive. But creates a second file.

I did this for a project where I needed to trace an specific problem and all those stupid messages where getting in the middle.

Comment: @stamp31sd: I'm glad. So, would my answer be marked as accepted? ( you know the green thick over there :P )

Answer (score 0):

Try modifying the `ObjectOutputStream`, not the serialized object.

If you extend `ObjectOutputStream`, you can override the `replaceObject` method and clear the non-serializable fields or re-create the object without the non-serializable properties.

Another option is to use reflection to nullify the non-serializable fields of the session objects, but that is very risky as a session object could be loaded back and appear to work but then throw a `NullPointerException` hours or even months later (when the field you nullified is eventually referenced.)

Modifying the classes will probably not work.

It is possible to extend `ClassLoader` and tweak flags on instance fields but:

- If it's your class that contains the non-serializable field then it's simpler to change the code yourself to make it transient
- If it's not your class then it will be loaded by a different `ClassLoader` from your application classes so by the time you see the object it will be too late (because the class has already been loaded.)

You cannot set the `transient` flag on an individual object, only on a class.

Comment: It's the app server that is doing the serialisation.

Answer (score 0):

Why go to that trouble?  It sounds just as easy to mark them all as Serializable, as long as all the objects in question are yours.

If that's not possible, .aAnother way is to have a class registered within your webApp that implements HttpSessionAttributeListener.  In the attributeAdded method print the sessionID and then serialize the session data:

```
public void attributeAdded(HttpSessionBindingEvent hsbe)
{
    // Handle the details yourself here.
    ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(hsbe.getValue())
}
```

Comment: trying to get arround not going through the classes (there are hundreds of them to mark them serializable and any other objects in their object graph as serializable